# Issue with wordpress thumnails - same thumnail displayed everywhere

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have this piece of code

```
  <?php

                $loop = new WP_Query(array('post__not_in' => array($latestId),'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 9,'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 )));
                $i=1;
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent_posts[0]['ID']), 'full' );

    $thumbnailImg=$image[0]?$image[0]:catch_that_image($recent_posts[0]);
?>
```

That I follow then with

```
<div 
            class="post-card__thumb__img h-bg-zoom__img" 
            style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumbnailImg; ?>');"></div>
```

But all I get is the thumbnail from the last written post displayed everywhere (rather than the thumbnail of each specific post).

Something is obviously wrong with my loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: try adding `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is this: `$recent_posts[0]['ID']`; and I don't see `$recent_posts` being defined in your code, so what exactly is that `$recent_posts` and where/how did you define it?:

```php
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent_posts[0]['ID']), 'full' );
```

And you're inside The Loop, so you could just call `get_post_thumbnail_id()` without having to specify the post ID — or use `get_the_ID()` to get the current post's ID:

```php
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' ); // use this or below
//$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' );
```

And I think the `$thumbnailImg=$image[0]?$image[0]:catch_that_image($recent_posts[0]);` should also be:

```php
$thumbnailImg=$image[0]?$image[0]:catch_that_image( get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed it :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)